# If $f_n\to f$ uniformly on [a,b] and f is continious on [a,b] then $f_n$ is continious in [a,b]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

Yesterday I wrote a test in calculus and had to answer the following question:

> Prove or contradict: if $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and f is continious on [a,b] then $\exists n_0\in\mathbb N$ s.t $\forall n>n_0,f_n$ is continious in $[a,b]$.

I proved it it in the following. Let $\epsilon>0$. The convergence is unifrom so $\exists n_1\in\mathbb N$ s.t $$\forall n>n_1,\forall x\in [a,b], |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac \epsilon 3$$. Also the f is continious on [a,b] so it means that for every $x_0\in [a,b]$ exists a $\delta_{f}$ s.t $$|x-x_0|<\delta_f\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac\epsilon 3$$. Then by choosing $n_0=n_1+1,\delta_{f_n}=\delta_f>0$, if $\forall n>n_0 \forall x\in[a,b],|x-x_0|<\delta_{f_n}$ then $$|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|=|f_n(x)+f(x)-f(x)+f(x_0)-f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|\le |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|<\frac \epsilon 3+\frac \epsilon 3+\frac \epsilon 3=\epsilon$$  and f is continious in these terms. Another friedn of mine claims he contradict the question by taking $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }x\neq0 \\
\frac 1 n, & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}$ which converge uniformly to 0 and is not continious on [0,1]. Which one of us is right and why the other is not?

Comment: Your friend is correct. I don't understand your proof, but your friend's counter example is certainly correct.

Comment: Your friend is right. The problem in your argument is that it works only for those $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\lvert f - f_n\rvert < \varepsilon/3$, but you'd need the estimate to hold for _all_ $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Your friend is correct. You haven't shown that there is a fixed $n$ such that $f_n$ is continuous: the smaller $\epsilon$, the larger $n_1$ will be.

Comment: It is well known that every function, continuous on a compact interval, is the uniform limit of a sequence of step functions, i.e., as one says, it is a _regulated_ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to apply your proof to the (valid) counterexample of your friend.

Can you show that $f_n$ is continuos at $x=0$? Lets assume $\epsilon=\frac1n$ is given. Can you find $\delta>0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_n(0)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x-0|<\delta$?
The problem when attempting so is: Your proof requires one to choose $n$ after $\epsilon$ is given. But to show continuity of $f_n$, we go the other way around: $n$ is given (first) to specify which function we investigate for continuiuty, then $x_0$ and then $\epsilon$. As you see, chosing $\epsilon <\frac1n$ for $f_n$ as given by your friend and $x_0=0$, breaks your proof.